# How to explain gensim word2vec output?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I run the following code and just wonder why the top 3 most similar words for "exposure" don't include "charge" and "lend"?

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
corpus = [['total', 'exposure', 'charge', 'lend'],
          ['customer', 'paydown', 'rate', 'months', 'month']]
gens_mod = Word2Vec(corpus, min_count=1, vector_size=300, window=2, sg=1, workers=1, seed=1)
keyword="exposure"
gens_mod.wv.most_similar(keyword)

Output:
[('customer', 0.12233059108257294),
 ('month', 0.008674687705934048),
 ('total', -0.011738087050616741),
 ('rate', -0.03600010275840759),
 ('months', -0.04291829466819763),
 ('paydown', -0.044823747128248215),
 ('lend', -0.05356598272919655),
 ('charge', -0.07367636263370514)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word2vec algorithm is only useful & valuable with large amounts of training data, where every word of interest has a variety of realistic, subtly-contrasting usage examples.

A toy-sized dataset won't show its value. It's always a bad idea to set `min_count=1`. And, it's nonsensical to try to train 300-dimensional word-vectors from a corpus of only 9 words, 9 unique words, and most of the words having the exact same neighbors.

Try it on a more realistic dataset - tens-of-thousands of unique words, all with multiple usage examples – and you'll see more intuitively-correct similarity results.

Comment: how to decide the value of min_count?

Comment: Stick with at least the default `min_count=5` if at all possible. As your corpus gets larger, try even-higher values in order to shrink the RAM size and training-time your final model. At some point you'll likely find *higher* values of `min_count` improve realistic task-based evaluations of final model quality.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do evaluations of final model quality? Also is there a rule of thumb for setting vector_size?

Comment: Evaluation should be driven by your specific purpose in using word2vec. Ideally you work up some starting set of expected/desirable results, for your purposes in your intended use, and test models against how well they satisfy those probes - which ideally are a representative set of the kind of other future untested cases. It's typical to grow the evaluation with tricky new cases over time - when you realize the early/ad-hoc stuff didn't cover all important cases.

Comment: There are a few similarity-ranking or analogy-solving standard evaluations of word-vectors which have commonly been used - but they're pretty narrow. For example, a lot of word2vec-related papers have used a set of `question-words.txt` analogies from the original word2vec paper, & there's support in Gensim for that in the method: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.evaluate_word_analogies - but word-vectors that score best on that may do worse on common classification or info-retrieval tasks! So, usually better to use your own eval.

Comment: There's no hard rules on vector-size, but generally larger training data & larger vocabularies support larger vectors. Very roughly, I don't think vector-size should be much larger than the square-root of the number of unique words in your vocabulary. So I'd not try to make 100-dimensional vectors with a vocabulary of less than 10000 words (each with many usage examples), and the commonly-usd 300-400 dimensionality really should be supported by a unique vocabulary of 100k-150k words or more. (The 300-dimension `GoogleNews` vectors are for a vocabulary of 3 million unique words.)